# Load zlib compressed data from a file with data offset in Perl

Tags: perl, io, compression, zlib

I want my perl script to load the binary data from a file. However this file can either be directly loaded or needs to be uncompressed (zlib) if the header `_ISCOMPRESSED_` is present a the begining of the file.

I've been able to successfully load the uncompressed file and recognise the header:

```pl
(open my ($fh), "<", $fileName) or (return 0);
binmode $fh;

my $fileHeader;
sysread $fh, $fileHeader, 14;
if( $fileHeader eq "_ISCOMPRESSED_" ){
  # Here, need to decompress the filestream and update the $fh to point toward uncompressed data 
}
else{
  # Read it from the begining
  sysseek $fh,0,0;
}

# Read the data using the file handle
sysread $fh,$self->{'sig'},4;
sysread $fh,$self->{'version'},4;
```

I'd like now to decompress with Zlib the chunck of data and update the file handle `$fh` to dispense uncompressed data.

How should I do and is it possible to do it without writing the uncompressed data on disk?

Comment: Bad idea to mix `read` and `sysread` on the same filehandle, btw.

Comment: Does the compressed part start immediately after the initial `_ISCOMPRESSED_`  sequence?

Comment: I see, I didn't write the whole code and the `sysread` part is the one that was previously there. Should I replace `read` by `sysread` then?

Comment: Yes it does directly start after `_ISCOMPRESSED_`

Comment: And which form of compression is used? zlib, gzip, raw DEFLATE? zlib supports a few different types (Mainly different in their headers IIRC)

Comment: It is Zlib compressed data, default compression. I can extract the data in command line with `zlib-flate -uncompress < file.zlib > file.extracted`

Comment: See [the documentation for Compress::Zlib](https://perldoc.perl.org/Compress::Zlib#Inflate-Interface). It is basically initializing the decompressor using `$z = inflateInit(...)` and then feeding it new data with `$z->inflate($buffer)` which returns the decompressed data. There is even an [example in the documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/Compress::Zlib#Example1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decompression modules that come with perl can read from an existing open file handle. The reading will start at the current offset, making it easy to skip the header. The `IO::Uncompress::*` modules in particular create file handle objects that can be used with normal I/O functions to allow transparent use; after creating it, your code doesn't care if it's a compressed or plain source file. Something like:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
# I don't have a zlib-flate to test for sure; I think this is the right module
use IO::Uncompress::Inflate;

my $fileName = "data.compressed";

my $fh;
open my $realfh, "<:raw", $fileName
    or die "Unable to open $fileName: $!\n";
read $realfh, my $header, 14;
if ($header eq "_ISCOMPRESSED_") {
    $fh = IO::Uncompress::Inflate->new($realfh, AutoClose => 1)
        or die "Unable to open decompression stream!\n";
} else {
    seek $realfh, 0, 0;
    $fh = $realfh;
}

read $fh, $self->{'sig'}, 4;
read $fh, $self->{'version'}, 4;
# etc.
close $fh;
```

---

If you're doing a lot of small input operations like you seem to, I'd use `read` over `sysread` to take advantage of the internal buffering. But the important thing is to be consistent; mixing the two forms on the same file handle will lead to problems with seemingly missing data.

Comment: Might need `IO::Uncompress::RawInflate` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! It does work with `IO::Uncompress::Inflate`

Comment: However it seems not possible to backward `seek` with `IO::Uncompress::Inflate` like standard file. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @nadrino Yeah, you can only [seek forward](https://perldoc.perl.org/IO::Uncompress::Inflate#seek) and even that's a hack. That's normal with reading compressed data formats. Avoid seeking, or decompress the file entirely and then read it

Comment: Thank you for your help @Shawn, I finally found a workaround by writing the inflated date to a temp file!